# install apache ofbiz freezes at birt-container

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to install apache ofbiz on Ubuntu 14.04 and in the terminal when it gets starting a birt-container it will stop and do nothing for ever. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please enhance your question, how did you try to install OfBiz? Did you follow [this guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/Demo+and+Test+Setup+Guide#DemoandTestSetupGuide-Quick&EasySetup)?

Can you check you syslog while it seems to hang on the birt-container? (`tail -f /var/log/syslog`)

What architecture do you have?
Which version of OfBiz are you installing?
Is there any error?
Do you have all the requirements (e.g. Java 1.8) and up to date?
Is there a specific log file of the installation?

Comment: I am not sure about chops. Suprisingly there were no error messages in logs of both installers and system

I have installed it using the link which you embedded above [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/Demo+and+Test+Setup+Guide#DemoandTestSetupGuide-Quick&EasySetup)

  
Java version: openjdk version "1.8.0_111"  
OS Version: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago)  
Apache OFbiz Version: apache-ofbiz-16.11.01